# Regex matches first and last character of a string, but why?

Tags: regex

This regex will match the first and the last character of a string:

```
/^.|.$/g
```

but why? Shouldn't it be the first 'OR' the last character? Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is matching multiple times due to use of `g` (global) switch.

If you want only one match then remove `g` flag:

```
/^.|.$/
```

Comment: (...and then you'll always get the first character, unless it's a newline...)

Answer (score 1):

`/^.|.$/` matches the first or the last character, but you added the `g`  (global) modifier, which means you will get both.